# remove last item in list inside list and then add a value to a list in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list

```
[['4', '150'], ['1'], ['1', '300'], [], ['75'], ['50'], [], []]
```

how can remove the last value in the lists that contain 2 values but then add a specified value like '1' to the empty lists

output should be

`[['4'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['75'], ['50'], ['1'], ['1']]`

I'm using python 3

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sub-lists never contain more than 2 items, you can do this:

```
L = [['4', '150'], ['1'], ['1', '300'], [], ['75'], ['50'], [], []]
D = '1'

L = [[*sl,D][:1] for sl in L]

print(L) # [['4'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['75'], ['50'], ['1'], ['1']]
```

The `[*sl,D][:1]` part adds the default value (D) to the list and then takes only the 1st element of the result.

So, if the list has two elements (e.g. `['4', '150']` --> `['4', '150','1'][:1]` --> `['4']`)

If the sub list is empty: `['1'][:1]` --> `['1']`

Answer (score 1):

Take the first element or (if there is none) use the default:

```
>>> [s[:1] or ['1'] for s in a]
[['4'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['75'], ['50'], ['1'], ['1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my own question using:

```
amount_list = [['4', '150'], ['1'], ['1', '300'], [], ['75'], ['50'], [], []]

    for item in amount_list:
        if len(item) > 1:
            item.pop()
        elif not item:
            item.append('1')
```

output is what i needed:

`[['4'], ['1'], ['1'], ['1'], ['75'], ['50'], ['1'], ['1']]`